# Include External Library in the ruby Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

I am trying to include the [Twitter External Library](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/tree/48efb642beaa19355a4c1ba04a9fadac54cfba42) in my Ruby code.
I have copied the Twitter library folder in my current directory.
And added `require_relative './twitterLib'` in my ruby code.
But while doing so, I am getting the following Error:

```
testFile_twitterAPI.rb:10:in `require_relative':
cannot load such file -- ./twitter/twitterLib (LoadError)
        from testFile_twitterAPI.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

My Current directory: `./twitter`

Can someone please tell how can I resolve this ?

Comment: try put it to `lib` directory

Comment: where `testFile_twitterAPI.rb` is located?

Comment: I tried putting the twitterLib package to lib directory. But still the same error. Both testFile_twitterAPI.rb file and twitterLib package are located at path: ~/lib/socialmedia/twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include a library by copying the code. Use gems instead. Gems are package of ruby code that are delivered in a specific format with the code, documentation and any configuration needed.

On the command line, type:

```
gem install twitter
```

You can then use require in the files where you need to use the library:

```
require 'twitter'
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to use the library without using 'gem install twitter' command ?

Comment: whenever I try 'gem install twitter', it says: "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'twitter' (>= 0) in any repository". whenever I try 'sudo yum install twitterLib', it says: "No package twitterLib available."

Comment: I just tested it right now without any problem. Not using gems will make your life very difficult for everything but the simplest task. There should be something wrong with your setup there. gem install should work.

Comment: whenever I try 'gem install twitter', it says: "ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'twitter' (>= 0) in any repository". Can you please suggest how can i resolve this ?